# Truncate the first 5 values of a value in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, truncate

I have two tables that I am trying to join on bigquery. I am joining them on serial numbers but for one of the tables the serial numbers start with 5 zeros and on the other one it does not. How can I write this join with the values truncated?

Can I do this in the join or do I have to do it prior and save that as a new table?

```
SELECT * FROM [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.PT_Results] AS Model_Results
JOIN [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.Master_List_PT] as Master_List on Serial=Serial_Number
```

The table that has the 5 zeros is PT_Results.

For example...
PT_Results serial# = 0000028106
Master_list_PT serial # = 28106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting both columns to int:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTR(CAST(CAST(Serial AS INT) AS STRING), 1, 5) AS Serial,
        Latest_Use,
        Total_Hours,
        Devices_Connected
    FROM [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.PT_Results]
) AS Model_Results
JOIN
(
    SELECT
       SUBSTR(CAST(CAST(Serial_Number AS INT) AS STRING), 1, 5) AS Serial_Number,
       Status,
       Model_Number
    FROM [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.Master_List_PT]
) AS Master_List
    ON Model_Results.Serial = Master_List.Serial_Number
```

Casting `Serial` to integer should remove the leading zeroes from the point of view of comparison.  Note that I used a derived table to do the cast so that the `ON` clause only involves pure columns and no functions.

**Update:**

If you want to compare the first five digits from *both* serial columns *after* the leading zeroes have been stripped you could try double casting:

```
SUBSTR(CAST(CAST(Serial AS INT) AS STRING), 1, 5)
```

Comment: I tried this and this is the error i am receiving. ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. Consider using Standard SQL .google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), which allows non-equality JOINs and comparisons involving expressions and residual predicates.

Comment: You may have to use a derived table then.  Update your question with the columns from both tables.  This could get ugly.

Comment: PT_Results = Serial Latest_Use Total_Hours Devices_Connected     This one is a derived table I queried these results out of a larger table

Comment: Master_List_PT = Serial_Number Status Model_Number

Comment: @W.Stephens Let me know if my current query works for you.

Comment: I think that I also have to cast the serial_number because it is inputted as a string and "Join keys Serial (int64) and Serial_Number (string) have types that cannot be automatically coerced." is the error im getting back

Comment: follow up question that I think may be out of the scope of this question. For some of the 'serial_number' values they end with a letter but they dont in the 'serial' value. Is there a way to look over this this also? I would assume just truncating any values over 5 characters?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to compare the first 5 characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148185/discussion-between-w-stephens-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I cannot chat now.  When you get a chance, reply to my question and I will try to help you.  Maybe `SUBSTR(Serial, 5)`

Comment: I want to compare the first 5 characters after the beginning zeros from 'serial' are removed

Comment: at what point in the code would I add the SUBSTR(serial,5) because adding it at the end with or without any indentation does not run

Comment: Check my updated answer.  Do two casts: one to remove leading zeroes and then cast again to bring it back to string, then use substring.

Comment: I am now getting this error Encountered " "AS" "AS "" at line 4, column 41. Was expecting: ")" ...

Comment: I unclicked the check so I believe you will be able to edit the original answer now

Comment: You don't need to uncheck in order for me to be able to edit.

Comment: Im still recieving the same error as before. Thanks so much for your help by the way

Comment: I don't know Big Query that well.  What I suggested should be working.  See if you can get the double cast to work here.